# Enabling dashes (hyphens) in a number column in SharePoint

Tags: number

How do you allow dashes (hyphens) to be used in a number column in SharePoint?
SharePoint only allows numbers and nothing else in number columns. 
Is there a formula or a calculated column that can be used to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

As Rodrigo has mentioned you cannot use hyphens on a number column. Another way is to create a single line of text column and use Input mask to force the user to enter value in certain format.

Check the reference: [Input mask on textbox in SharePoint list form](http://pawansatope.blogspot.in/2012/02/input-mask-on-textbox-in-sharepoint.html)

You have to enter below script on your list form

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script language="javascript" src="http://jquery-joshbush.googlecode.com/files/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
   $("input[title='YourFieldName']").mask("999-999-9999");
});
</script>
```

The above script will force the user to enter only number in US phone format.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use hyphens on a number column `(unless is a negative number)`. You should use a text column with a validation formula.

For example, lets say you want to store a phone number with the format `xxx-xxx-xxxx.`

The formula then would be:

```
=AND(AND(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("???-???-????",YourFieldName,1))),LEN(YourFieldName)=12),AND(AND(ISNUMBER(MID(YourFieldName,1,3)+0),ISNUMBER(MID(YourFieldName,5,3)+0)),ISNUMBER(MID(YourFieldName,9,4)+0)))
```

Source: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com.ar/2015/10/sharepoint-column-validation-examples.html